# python gevent: identify which thread in a pool

Tags: python-2.7, concurrency, gevent

Is there a way, when running [gevents](http://www.gevent.org/) in a pool, to identify somehow which thread in the pool is running at a give time?  This is useful for logging.

For example:

```
from gevent.pool import Pool

def func(arg):
  pool_id = #some way to id the pool
  logger.debug("[{}] {}".format(pool_id, arg))

pool = Pool(10):
pool.map(func, range(50))
```

Answer (score 0):

[threading.current_thread()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.current_thread)

or

[threading.get_ident()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.get_ident) for python >= 3.3.

Comment: this only works if the threads were created using the threading module.  In this case, I'm using [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/)

Comment: Doesn't gevent also create thread using the threading module?

Comment: @YassineFaris threading module uses OS-level threads which provide no benefit with CPU-bound tasks. gevent uses green threads which run under an implicit event loop, and switch on IO tasks.